# tableViewCell.roundCorners are not shown immediately

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

I have these methods for collectionViewCell

```
cell.restarauntImage.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: 10, borderColor: UIColor.clearColor(), borderWidth: 0)
```

and tableViewCell

```
cell.restImage.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: 7, borderColor: UIColor.clearColor(), borderWidth: 0)
```

the problem is that it works perfectly with collectionView, but in tableView it is not working instantly with .TopRight, it applies only if I reuse cell several times, however .TopLeft works. Also if I remove .TopLeft and try to apply only to .TopRight it doesn't work either. What might be the problem?

update: extension found on stack overflow

```
extension UIView {
func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat)
{
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
    addBorder(mask, borderWidth: borderWidth, borderColor: borderColor)
}

private func addBorder(mask: CAShapeLayer, borderWidth: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor) {
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = mask.path
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.CGColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
    borderLayer.frame = bounds
    layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}
}
```

update2: cellForRowAtIndexPath, I've tried to put this method to each case after ink_setImage, but it didn't work either.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell
        cell.restImage.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: 10, borderColor: UIColor.clearColor(), borderWidth: 0)
        cell.backgroundGray.roundCorners([.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], radius: 7, borderColor: UIColor.clearColor(), borderWidth: 0)
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.restImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: "https://pp.vk.me/c636117/v636117560/29385/OukzPhoe4q0.jpg")!)
        case 1:
            cell.restImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: "https://pp.vk.me/c636117/v636117560/29385/OukzPhoe4q0.jpg")!)
        case 2:
            cell.restImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: "https://pp.vk.me/c636117/v636117560/29385/OukzPhoe4q0.jpg")!)
        case 3:
            cell.restImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: "https://pp.vk.me/c636117/v636117560/29385/OukzPhoe4q0.jpg")!)
        default:
            cell.restImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: "https://pp.vk.me/c636117/v636117560/29385/OukzPhoe4q0.jpg")!)
        return cell
}
}
```

Comment: What does your roundCorners method look like? This isn't a method provided by UIKit…

Comment: added extension code to topic

Comment: show us cellforrowatindexpath method please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I just added this function in dispatch_async like this and it works

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
self.content.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.content.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
self.restarauntImage.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: 6, borderColor: UIColor.clearColor(), borderWidth: 0)
self.content.roundCorners([.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], radius: 6,  borderColor: UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1),  borderWidth: 1)})
```

}

what's more if you change number of views in your cell dynamically (for example the bottom one can be hidden), you have to add these lines of code in your cellForIndexPath to make reusable cells draw borders correctly

```
    cell.bottomDataView.hidden = false //show elements you have hidden
    cell.backgroundGray.layer.mask = nil //delete previous mask
    if cell.bottomDataView.layer.sublayers?.count > 2 {
        cell.bottomDataView.layer.sublayers?.removeLast() //delete previous layer
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `self.tableView.reloadData()` call at the end of your `viewDidLoad` method, this might fix the delay problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your implemenataion seems too complicated for just setting a corner radius to an imageView.
all you have to do is:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = <the radius>
```

Sometimes, you may need to apply:

```
imageView.clipToBounds = true
```

Comment: I need to set this radius only for top 2 corners, not for all 4

Comment: got it. did you try clipToBounds = true? it may help

Comment: yeap, I did to both my image and my view, didn't help.